# Full Calendar and Django Save Events

Tags: python, json, django, calendar

Sorry for my english, as I do to salvage a json coming from the full calendar.

I'm doing the agenda of a physician, and the full calendar events come as json.

view from the attempt to save.
Here my views.py :

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    objecto_profesional = Empleado.objects.get(id=self.request.POST['profesional'])
        form.instance.profesional = objecto_profesional
        turnos = self.request.POST['JSONParse']
        decoded_json = json.loads(turnos)
        i = 0
        for fila in decoded_json:
            print(decoded_json[i])
            c = Calendario(**decoded_json[i])
            c.save()
            i = i + 1
        return super(AgendaCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

an error:

```
TypeError at /agendas/agregar/16/


'allDay' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Class Calendario :

```
class Calendario(models.Model):   
    agenda = models.ForeignKey(Agenda, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    all_day = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

class Agenda :

```
class Agenda(models.Model):
    fecha_desde = models.DateField()
    fecha_hasta = models.DateField()
    profesional = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, blank=True, null=True)
    tipo_turno = models.ForeignKey(TipoTurnoAgenda, blank=False, null=False)
    cantidad_turno = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    duracion_turno = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ventana = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    habilitado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Agendas"
```

PLease, help me.

and sorry for my english. It's my first time here

Comment: Please post the definition of the Calendario class. (And please don't use a loop index variable: `fila` is the current element inside the loop, use that rather than `decoded_json[i]`.)

Comment: Thanks, mi Calendario Class is :

class Calendario(models.Model):

    agenda = models.ForeignKey(Agenda, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    all_day = models.BooleanField(default=False)

again, sorry for my English , I'm new too in django

Comment: i am using fullcalendar.io

Comment: for fila in decoded_json:
            print(fila)
            c = Calendario(**fila)
            c.save()

Comment: Well, looks like your field is called `all_day` but your JSON has an `allDay` key instead. Those are not the same.

Comment: I feel a fool, thanks,  sorry for your time. awesome answer.
Thanks !